# PHP post variable error

Tags: php, post, echo

I have a code and I want it to do the next task : if all POST variables are set, it echos something. If not, the POST variables get another value and then it echos too.

The problem is that if the variables are not set, the new value does not echo. I have only a blank.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

```html
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['nom']) AND isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['cars']) AND isset($_POST['km'])) 
 {
  
  echo 'Nom : ' . $_POST['nom'] . '</br>';
  echo 'Email : ' . $_POST['email']. '</br>';
  echo 'La marque de votre voiture est : ' .$_POST['cars'] . '</br>';
  echo 'Votre kilométrage actuel est : ' . $_POST['km'] . '</br>';
  
 }
 
 

 else
 {
  $null='manquant';
  if (!isset($_POST['nom']))
  {
   $_POST['nom'] = $null;
  }
  if (!isset($_POST['email']))
  {
   $_POST['email'] = $null;
  }
  if (!isset($_POST['cars']))
  {
   $_POST['cars'] = $null;
  }
  if (!isset($_POST['km']))
  {
   $_POST['km'] = $null;
  }
 
  echo 'Nom : ' . $_POST['nom'] . '</br>';
  echo 'Email : ' . $_POST['email']. '</br>';
  echo 'La marque de votre voiture est : ' .$_POST['cars'] . '</br>';
  echo 'Votre kilométrage actuel est : ' . $_POST['km'] . '</br>';
 }
?>
```

Here is the form code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Mon formulaire</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="analyse.php" method="post">
  <label for="nom">Votre nom : <input type="text" name="nom"> </label>
  <label for="email">Votre email : <input type="email" name="email"> </label>
  <label for="cars">La marque de votre voiture : </label>
  <select name="cars">
   <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
   <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  </select
  <label for="km">Votre kilometrage (en km) : <input type="text" name="km"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="valider">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you use again isset in else condition ?

Comment: All those $_POST values look as though they've been entered in <input type='text'....> type fields. If that is the case then HTML will submit these items even if they are blank. You need to test for !empyt($_POST['nom']) or $_POST['nom'] != "" or trim($_POST['nom']) != ""

Comment: Can you var_dump($_POST); ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a blank `<option>` so that it satisfies the condition that all fields are blank.

```
<select name="cars">
<option value="">empty</option> <-- add this line
<option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
```

Also, change this line to use `!empty()` instead. `isset()` still evaluates to `true` even if an empty field is submitted.

```
if (!empty($_POST['nom']) AND !empty($_POST['email']) AND !empty($_POST['cars']) AND !empty($_POST['km']))
```

AND

```
if (empty($_POST['nom']))
{
    $_POST['nom'] = $null;
}
if (empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $_POST['email'] = $null;
}
if (empty($_POST['cars']))
{
    $_POST['cars'] = $null;
}
if (empty($_POST['km']))
{
    $_POST['km'] = $null;
}
```

Comment: I have done that, but the POST variables do not display their new value if the inputs are empty

Comment: @PNB I missed out another error, I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['nom']) AND isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['cars']) AND isset($_POST['km'])) 
 {
  
  echo 'Nom : ' . $_POST['nom'] . '</br>';
  echo 'Email : ' . $_POST['email']. '</br>';
  echo 'La marque de votre voiture est : ' .$_POST['cars'] . '</br>';
  echo 'Votre kilométrage actuel est : ' . $_POST['km'] . '</br>';
  
 }
 
 
 
 else
 {
  $null='manquant';
  if (empty($_POST['nom']))
  {
   $_POST['nom'] = $null;
  }
  if (empty($_POST['email']))
  {
   $_POST['email'] = $null;
  }
  if (empty($_POST['cars']))
  {
   $_POST['cars'] = $null;
  }
  if (empty($_POST['km']))
  {
   $_POST['km'] = $null;
  }
 
  echo 'Nom : ' . $_POST['nom'] . '</br>';
  echo 'Email : ' . $_POST['email']. '</br>';
  echo 'La marque de votre voiture est : ' .$_POST['cars'] . '</br>';
  echo 'Votre kilométrage actuel est : ' . $_POST['km'] . '</br>';
 }
?>
```

have you try with the empty ?